# What can I do to improve the sound of a signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, fourier, sound, amplitude

I want to improve the sound of my signal, I know I can do it by increasing or decreasing the amplitude of the signal itself. Are there any other ways to do this? How can I apply the Fourier transform in this?

Comment: This question is too vague to be reasonably addressed. What kind of signal? What kind of flaws does it have that needs improvement?

Comment: I apologize for not having specified better. I mean a periodic signal. By improving the sound I meant that it has some distortion or, more generally, it is not a clean signal.

Comment: Speech? A motor? Ocean waves? Does it clip? Soft saturate? Can you make a plot and point to rhe flaws?

Comment: I'm taking a sample code at random, it doesn't really have any particular or specific features. We can imagine that it has an external disturbance which can be, for example, a building that disturbs a radio wave communication. I hope I was clearer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.